# JS Get all responses while loading

Tags: javascript

I want to get all my pending responses in my website but I have a problem here. For example if I use Fetch for this like this:

```
fetch("http://******.herokuapp.com/").then(response => {
    console.log(response)
})
```

This will return me one response with status code 200 OK. But is there a way to get all responses in array or somewhere while my page is loading using `fetch` or another method ?

Answer (score 1):

Dispatched requests will not get stored automatically. You can either create your own wrapper function which stores responses somewhere, or alternatively you can store your pending promises in an array, for example:

```js
const promises = [
  fetch('resource1'),
  fetch('resource2'),
  ...
]
```

Using [Promise.all(promises)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) returns a promise which resolves when all of the passed promises in the array have resolved:

> The Promise.all() method returns a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises passed as an iterable have resolved or when the iterable contains no promises. It rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects.

In contrast [Promise.race(promises)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) resolves as soon as one promise in the array is resolved.